# Exception Description: An incompatible mapping has been encountered between [class sws.entities.Appointment] and [class sws.entities.User]

Tags: java, entity-framework, jpa

Hi guys i am having a major issue with my many to many mappings

i am getting the error

```
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7244] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An incompatible mapping has been encountered between [class sws.entities.Appointment] and [class sws.entities.User]. This usually occurs when the cardinality of a mapping does not correspond with the cardinality of its backpointer.
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
```

here are my entities

```
@Entity
public class Appointment implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date startDatetime, endDatetime;
    private String appointmentDescription;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "username")
    private User owner;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "appointments")
    private Collection<User> attendees;
```

and

```
@Entity(name = "USERS")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Address address;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String firstName, surname, telephoneNumber, emailAddress, gender;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "PASSWD", length = 32, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(32)")
    private String password;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private Role role;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date DateOfBirth;

    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Appointment> appointments;
```

i have done a google and can not find out why this is doing this, any ideas ?

Comment: When is the exception thrown? As this is a bidirectional relationship, when you manipulate one entity, do you manipulate also the other?

Comment: on complie, i can not get it to run to test this

Comment: Are these all persistable fields in these 2 entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the real problem is here:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "username")
private User owner;
```

`mappedBy` is used to connect different sides of bidirectional relationship (e.g. `attendees` and `appointments`). `owner` is a unidirectional relationship, therefore you don't need `mappedBy` here:

```
@OneToOne
private User owner;
```

Comment: Exactly that I was looking for with my last question :))